# Is there a way to create a list of classes, but not call them until you loop through them?

Tags: python

I've created a list of classes that I'm importing from another file, there are about 50 which is why I'm trying to do it this way. The below list is in my `__init__.py` file:

```
TABLES = [
   Accounts(),
   Activities()
]
```

but I want to actually call them here because I need to add `company` names for each table.

```
for table in TABLES:
    snowflake = SnowflakeLoadOperator(
        task_id=f'load_{table.name}_to_snowflake',
        table=table(company='company_name_1'),
        partition=table.get_location_partition(ds)
    )

for table in TABLES:
    snowflake = SnowflakeLoadOperator(
        task_id=f'load_{table.name}_to_snowflake',
        table=table(company='company_name_2'),
        partition=table.get_location_partition(ds)
    )
```

but I keep seeing the error:

> table=table(company='company_name_1'), TypeError: 'Accounts' object is
> not callable

This is what one of my classes look like, similar methods but different values:

```
class Accounts(Table):
    name = None
    schema = 'accounts'

    def __init__(self, company=None):
        self.name = f'{company}_accounts'
        self.location_base = f's3://my_bucket/{self.schema.upper()}/{company}/accounts/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the parentheses in the definition of `TABLES` and you'll store references to the classes themselves, rather than constructing instances of them:

```
TABLES = [
   Accounts,
   Activities
]
```

Then you'll be able to call them when looping later, using `table(arg)` the same way you'd use `Accounts(arg)` or `Activities(arg)`.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple fix. Your list right now contains *instances* of the classes, because you're *instantiating* them.

Just drop the parentheses after the class name to get a list of classes:

```py
TABLES = [Accounts, Activities]
```

and then it should work, because now `TABLES` contains the classes themselves, not some instantiation of them.

Comment: thank you for explaining!